# How to avoid conflicts between local variable names and symbolic arguments in Block constructs?

Tags: programming, scoping

I am using `Block` inside the definition of some recursive functions.

If the Block definitions use short variable names, like `{s = First[param], r = Rest[param]}`, an infinite recursion occurs when `param` contains one of the symbols `s` or `r`.

Using tortured local symbols names minimizes this risk, but

- it makes code unreadable,
- it does not prevent the collision risk, but only minimizes it.

**How to deal with local variable assignment without any collision risk?**

Substitution rules <strike>and Modules</strike> have their own problems with recursive functions, which is why I use Blocks, but it's maybe the wrong tool.

**Edit**: There is no good reason not to use Module, except if one wants to locally modify the recursion limit, it seems. For my part, I was just confused, and **I should just use Module**.

Comment: What is the problem with using `Module`? I think it would be the right tool here.

Comment: When there's a chance that symbols will be passed to your function, and you have no control over what those symbols might be (i.e. it's an end-user accessible function), then `Block` is almost never a good solution.   **So what's wrong with `Module`?**  It seems to me that `Module` is the way to go here, but you didn't explain what the problem is with it.

Comment: Why don't you provide a complete minimal self-contained example of what you are trying to achieve and which problems you encounter. Your current question does not contain enough information for a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs, one reason to use Block is to set a `$RecusionLimit`, which you can not do with Module.

Comment: @ruebenko That's true, but there `$RecursionLimit` is overridden on purpose.  If I understand it right, the OP is simply using `Block` for "local variables" (as in `f[x_] := Block[{s=1}, x+s]`)  If a symbol that's passed to the function has the same name as those local variables, then things will likely go wrong.

Comment: @ruebenko Personally, I tend to rewrite my code in a tail-recursive style as soon as I discover a need to change the `$RecursionLimit` - it is all to easy to crash the kernel resetting this value, and I would not trust the code which does that.

Comment: If you absolutely must use `Block` and cannot use `Module`, put the local variable symbols in a private context: ``Begin["myfun`"]; myfun[x_] := Block[{s=1}, x+s]; End[]``.  Now `myfun[s]` will return `s+1` as expected.

Comment: @Leonid Then you might need to increase `$IterationLimit`

Comment: You may find it useful to use `Block` on `Module` - localized variables, as e.g. described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394113/defining-a-function-with-an-optional-value-that-is-by-default-a-function-of-anot/7394668#7394668), where I tried to explain the advantages of this approach.

Comment: @Szabolcs But that's an entirely different story, because by increasing `$IterationLimit` you don't blow the stack and don't risk to crash the kernel. I have nothing against increasing `$IterationLimit`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I have never seen a crash with `Block[{$RecusionLimit=10},...]` and if there is one, it should be reported and fixed. Of course, using a tail recursive style is an option, but since M- is an infinite loop eval and linear list (not cons) based, I am not sure M- is tail recursive. Never tested this though.

Comment: @ruebenko I expressed my thoughts on tail-recusriveness in Mathematica [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481301/tail-call-optimization-in-mathematica/4627671#4627671), you may find that post of some interest. As to `Block[{$RecusionLimit=10},...]`, you can't set it to this value anyways (minimal is 20), and default of `256` is more than enough for most fixed-depth recursive functions. I've seen crashes as early as `$RecusionLimit` equal 1000 or so, and it's not a fixed value - depends on how soon the stack space is exhausted, and is problem-dependent. But that's besides the point -

Comment: @ruebenko  because such code *in principle* can not be made robust - you can never *guarantee* that a given recursion will not blow the stack. So, as soon as the default value of `$RecursionLimit` is not enough, I don't trust the code as robust any more. This is my personal view, of course.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks for the link - that was before my SE time ;-), I have a read. Of course you can run into trouble with running out of space - that's the point about tail recursive functions. But if you find such a crash, it were good to know about. The code just should not crash.

Comment: @ruebenko But my point is that, when a function is not tail-recursive, there is no general way to guarantee that the code is crash-free, and I think this is a general feature, not specific to Mathematica. You may have some heuristics, or you may know the details of your algorithm and the system (stack space), to be more or less sure, but that doesn't make this robust in the general sense - algorithms evolve, the analysis of an algorithm may contain mistakes, the stack space may vary across systems, etc. You just can't generally guarantee a crash-free behavior for a non-tail-recursive function.

Comment: @ruebenko @celtschk @Szabolcs @LeonidShifrin Thank you for your comments; Apart from the `$RecursionLimit` thing, I remember a problem with the scope of the local variables created with Module vs. Block. I can't b more precise because I'm not sufficiently proficient in Mathematica :) I will need to look it up when I can access my Mathematica.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, OK I got it, I miss understood you. I thought that the change in `$RecusionLimit` as such would lead to a crash. But you are taking about physical limits of memory like, say `LinearSolve` is running out of space for big matrices. Yes, then there is not much you can do about the crash.

Comment: @agravier, in that case it might be better to use Module and if you encounter a problem to show that here.

Comment: @ruebenko Yes, that's what I meant, and on top of that, the stack space is typically much smaller than, for example, available RAM, and is not allocated dynamically.

Comment: @agravier If that is your only concern, then just use `Module`.  `Block` will give you a lot more headache. Those problems don't typically come up.

Comment: I found why I didn't use `Module`. Not that I encountered any error myself, but I read http://math.stackexchange.com/a/28904 and half-understood that there is some sort of closure leakage when using Module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to have the `Module` inside the function, you can also put it around the function, and then use `Block` inside, as in

```
Module[{s,r},
  f[param_List]:=Block[{s = First[param], r = Rest[param]}, ... ]
]
```

However, for this special case, I'd use the abilities of the pattern matcher:

```
f[{s_,r___}] := ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually can use Module, I was confused. I will edit my question to clarify that and accept your answer :)

Comment: @agravier: Thank you for the accept.