# Odd edge-case behavior of Block

Tags: programming, scoping

In this example, `Block` is used to localize the variable cache as used in the function `g` when called from the function `f`.  In `f`, the cache symbol to use is passed in as the second parameter `z`:

```
f[a_, z_] := Block[{cache = z}, g[a]];
g[a_] := (Print["hash" -> Hash[cache]]; cache[1] = a; cache[1]);
```

Everything works as expected:

```
Hash[z] 
2065959314 (your number may be different)
```

Calling `f`:

```
f[1, z] 
hash->2065959314 (same) 
1
```

The symbol `z` now has a single downvalue:

```
DownValues[z] 
{HoldPattern[z[1]] :> 1}
```

However, what if I use the **actual symbol cache** as the cache symbol (say. by accident; not knowing that is the symbol name used inside `Block`):

```
Hash[cache] 
1028301578 (your number may be different)
```

Calling `f`:

```
f[1, cache] 
hash->1028301578 (same) 
1
```

But nothing stored in the cache this time?

```
DownValues[cache] 
{}
```

My (partial) theory is that `Block[{cache = cache}, ...]` may have used a temporary variable `cache$xxx` after `cache=cache` collapses, but that doesn't explain why we still see the correct hash for the symbol inside `g`. This is an awkward, but OK situation **if** you know the name of the variable used inside `Block`, but could conceivably lead to some very puzzling bugs (as it did for me) if you chance upon the same symbol name.

Comment: As noted in the tag description, please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag until your report has been confirmed by other people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is as designed (as it should be). In general, when you use

```
Block[{s = someExpression}, body]
```

then `s` is initialized with the value of `someExpression`, computed using the surrounding environment (usually `` Global` `` context). But then, all changes made to the properties of `s`, remain local to `Block` and are undone after the execution exits `Block`. In the particular case

```
Block[{cache = cache},...]
```

The assignments done in `g` are performed on the localized version of `cache`, and are therefore undone when `Block` exits, so everything works as it should.

A side note is that I would not recommend using code which changes the values of symbols which are not passed to it as parameters. The reasoning is basically the same as the usual recommendations against using global variables.  So, the code like

```
g[a_] := (Print["hash" -> Hash[cache]]; cache[1] = a; cache[1]);
```

is inherently prone to errors, because it modifies the symbol `cache` that has not been passed to it.  The puzzle you observed is just one manifestation of this.

Comment: Short and on point. :)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should consider the former as a major achievement:)

Comment: Edited to make it 2 characters shorter, +1

Comment: Thanks to Leonid, I will accept that answer.  I still feel this is a bug in the sense that I may not have written the function using Block and as such I am in guessing game to avoid the symbols used in a function I can't see inside.  Such conflicts have been seen before with iterator variables [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23529/how-do-i-avoid-scoping-collisions-of-iterator-variables?rq=1) and in another case like mine [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5109/how-to-avoid-conflicts-between-local-variable-names-and-symbolic-arguments-in-bl?rq=1)

Comment: Placing the functions in package does mitigate the problem as Global`cache would become SomePackage`cache.

Comment: @user880 Thanks for the accept. Re:bug - this is most certainly not a bug. Rather, this is an inappropriate use of `Block`. I have argued many times in my answers on this site and elsewhere that `Block` is in 99 % of cases not a proper tool to localize variables in functions - `With` and `Module` are. Rather, `Block` is a special-purpose scoping construct, with typical use cases quite different from those for lexical ones. In particular, `Block` does not create a new symbol but rather temporarily changes the value or other properties of an existing symbol.

Comment: @user880 In your case, you should have explicitly passed the symbol you want to modify, into your `g` function, and not use `Block` as a short-cut (but rather use `Module` if you really wanted to guarantee the uniqueness of your `cache` symbol). The necessity of avoid naming collisions clearly calls for lexical scoping, yet you used dynamic scoping instead - an invitation for trouble. In general, if you like to work with symbols like that, it would be good to get a deeper understanding of scoping in Mathematica.

Comment: My reasons want to do this. In my real problem _cache_ is used to hold randomly generated data constant; in very simple form. `g[a_]:=If[NumberQ[cache[a]],cache[a],cache[a]=Random[]];`.  The sharing of cache through _Block_ allows me to clear the cache when I want a new set of random values generated.  This is awkward to achieve without _Block_.  I would venture that if not a actually bug, behavior is consistent with documentation, as with the iterator example it does violate the principle of least surprise [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: @user880 Alas, Mathematica violates this principle in many cases. But `Block` is an advanced construct, so one has to be prepared and using `Block` generally requires a better familiarity with the language (unless one is ready to face suprises, often subtle ones). I am sure that your problem could be solved no less elegantly but more robustly though. In general, I would recommend giving more context when asking a question, for cases like this, since this will make it more likely that someone comes up a different and better solution than the one you are having problems with.